# How does Android Studio gradle plugin manage resource files (AndroidManifest.xml)?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-manifest

I have my project's `build.gradle` located in `myApp/app/` directory. `AndroidManifest.xml` is in `myApp/app/src/main` directory, at the same level as `java/` and `res/` directories.

When synchronizing the project, I receive notification about missing manifest file. No wonder, actually, when the path is really incorrect. Source file is set as:

```
    sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

and the error notification says:

`Error:Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/aqv/AndroidStudioProjects/myApp/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)`

When I change the source to:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

the text changes to:

`Error:Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/aqv/AndroidStudioProjects/myApp/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)`

As you can see, there is missing path fragment: `myApp/app/src/` (when setting `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` path, the error says about looking for manifest file in `myApp/src/main`, so it ommits the `app/` directory).

Is it a kind of gradle's bug or my project is misconfigured?

Looking for solution I found one thread at SO, but the solution from there didn't work in my case. I have dependencies set as:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
```

Comment: Did you modify your root `build.gradle` instead of `app/build.gradle`?

Comment: Yeah, that was the solution! Thanks, Man! Please add it as an answer so that I could upvote and close the thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing an answer since could be also issue for someone.

By default Android Studio creates multi module project. So you have `build.gradle` in the root folder of your project and another `build.gradle` in **app** folder:

```
<your project name>
/app
   /src
   build.gradle
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

The parent `build.gradle` is usually edited if you want to specify default settings for all subprojects. It looks odd since you have only one subproject for now.

The topic starter issue was that he was adding/modifying root `build.gradle` instead of **app** folder `build.gradle`.